# Unity 3d in touch sensitive webstore interface

Tags: mysql, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I need to create a touch version of the webstore with 3D elements. At the beginning I chose a WebGL technology because of the straightforward integration with databases (such interface will need to download thumbnails of products and basic information about it using MySQL).

Problem is the lack of simple tools to create such a project. Recently I became interested in Unity. I just don't know whether its capabilities allow me to do this. What do you think about Unity 3d? Is a good choice for such a task?

Comment: Welcome Martin. I removed the link to your home page because otherwise your question might be treated as spam and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Unity3D web player needs a plugin installed at the user's browser. This plugin is not available for iPhone and AFAIK for Android neither. Thus it is not possible to create a **pure** browser based online store solution.

What you can do with Unity3D as a workaround: Do the project in Unity3D and export it once as web version for desktop clients and then export it as app (i.e. a fat client that needs to be installed) for iPhone and again for Android. But even then you will have a lot of work providing different layouts for all target devices.

Although I like Unity3D very much, I would not recommend it for development of an online store.